# is epoch time the same on the same machine with diffent scripts/programs

Tags: javascript, shell, epoch

I want to use shell to get epoch time
and later use javascript on a html page to get another epoch time
and then get the difference between them
but I'm afraid that the epoch time may not be synchronized among different scripts
so this difference is useless

so I want to know, if at the very same time, I use shell and javascript to get epoch tiem
will the result be the same or not?
if not, how big is the difference?

thanks!

Comment: I am guessing they will be the same, but it cannot be trusted because browsers may do strange things or the user may change some settings or something. It'd be a lot better if you just used a server to get your epoch time.

Comment: I mean if the javascript run on the same machine as the shell script, will they be the same

Comment: I know what you meant. All I'm saying is that these things aren't always completely reliable since not everyone follows the specifications. Mostly, they should be the same, yes.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean number of seconds since Unix epoch (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z), it is governed by this very definition. The only differences you should be able to see are caused by:

- different times of invocation of the system call that returns it*);
- unsynchronized clocks on different systems.

and possibly also:

- unsynchronized clocks on different processor cores/physical processors;
- implementation dependent handling of the function that returns current time (e.g. JS engine implementation might possibly cache the value for a short time as not to have to do the actual syscall, although I would doubt this).

Depending on the time resolution you need, some of these are not a problem. My guess is, that if you don't need granularity finer than 1s, you should be more than fine (on the same machine).

*) also note, that on single core system, you can't really get the same time (at least with the ns resolution) from different syscalls, unless the kernel caches it, simply because they have to happen one after another.

Comment: Oh, the theory is a bit deep, so if I use shell script and javascript on the same machine, I hope the accuracy granularity be on the level of 0.2 second or below, is it possible or not?

Comment: @user1769686 I would expect so (actually I believe it should be more on the ms scale). Yet bear in mind that you can occasionally easily see larger lags due to higher load on the computer, especially in the browser displaying the page.

Answer (score 1):

According to [ECMA-262 section 15.9.1.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.1):

> Time is measured in ECMAScript in milliseconds since 01 January, 1970
>   UTC. In time values leap seconds are ignored. It is assumed that there
>   are exactly 86,400,000 milliseconds per day.

So, yes, every JavaScript implementation that adheres to standard must return exactly same values, taking care of any physical clock quirks by itself. Barring wrong set up of system clock you will have same value everywhere.

Note that definition of "epoch" and "seconds since" in other languages and systems could be different (at very least most other systems use seconds, not milliseconds and most often take leap seconds in account), so you can't guarantee that JS time, even divided by 1000 will match timestamp from another platform or OS.